# How do I get appscript to download the entirety of a large JSON?

Tags: json, github, google-apps-script

I'm writing a appscript script for google sheets. It accesses the Github API and then downloads a JSON from a relevant repository.

Currently I'm getting an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HYu7.png)

When I log the JSON object (as a string), it prints:

"Logging output too large. Truncating output."

...and then prints a truncated JSON. This makes me think that it isn't just the console log entry that is being truncated, but the JSON itself.

I did get a different version of this working in a node script, so I know that the JSON object on github is well-formed.

Can someone help me understand what's happening here? How can I get the whole JSON, so that I can get the info that I need from it?

Here's the whole script so far:

```
async function myFunction() {

  // Step 1. set up the spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();


  // Step 2: access the github API
  // from here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28

  // step 2.1: get the download url from github
  // from here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/etyre/Roam_Backup/contents/json', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
      "Accept": "application/vnd.github+json", 
      "Authorization": <token>
      "X-GitHub-Api-Version": "2022-11-28" 
          },
      })

  // Step 2.2: parse the download url that gives the Roam Database JSON (using appscript stuff)
  Logger.log(response);
  var dataString = response.getContentText(); // dataString is a string
  var wholeJsonObject = JSON.parse(dataString); // wholeJsonObject is a json object
  Logger.log(wholeJsonObject[0].download_url)
  var url = wholeJsonObject[0].download_url
  // We're using some google appscript specific syntax here. (see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external)

  // step 2.3: use the download url to get the whole graph as a JSON object, and parse it
  var response2 = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) 
  var dataString2 = response2.getContentText(); 

  Logger.log(dataString2)
  
  var fullDatabaseJSON = JSON.parse(dataString2);
  // fullDatabaseJSON = dataString2.split("},{");
  // Note that this /\ solves some error that we have with the JSON object.

  
  Logger.log(fullDatabaseJSON)

  //Step 3: Get the data we want from the downloaded JSON object
```

Things that I tried already:

- Stringifying the content and converting it into an array.
- Stringifying the content and then converting to JSON
- Converting to JSON without using the .getContentText function.

None of those worked.